# SolR - Search for room availability and sort by result

Tags: sorting, solr

I'm trying to implement a kind of hotel/hostel search using SolR and PHP. For any room available I store a new document inside my index containing relevant information about the accomodation and multivalued attributes containing an availableFrom and availableTill date. Running a query against SolR to get all rooms within a certain timespan shouldn't be that hard, but my brain screws up when it comes to sorting...

My goal is to show not only the available accomodations, but all of them matching a general filter query on the destination (country/city/district) and sort these results so that all available rooms are sorted to the start of the list.

So for a search for rooms in Munich from 1st December '12 till 5th December, I would like to get results like these:

- Room A (available)
- Room B (available)
- Room C (not completly available in the given period => nice to have)
- Room D (not available at all)

Currently I'm running SolR 3.6 but could switch to the new 4.0 if necessary.

Has any Solr-Guru out there some suggestions for me?
Any help appreciated :-)

-edit-

I think Samuele pushed me in the right direction. So the question is now, how to create a function query to be able to sort by availability. Maybe there is a better way to store my document, i.e. change my schema.xml?

Here is a litte excerpt from it:

```
<field name="recordId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="language" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="maxPersons" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="avgPrice" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="city" type="freetext" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="district" type="freetext" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="country" type="freetext" indexed="true" stored="false" />      
<field name="availableFrom" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="availableTill" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Cheers - Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you have to boost your query based on the field "rooms" (or availability, depends on you) and give different scores based on the value

quick example:

let's give an available room a boost of 20, a partial available a boost of 10 and not available a boost of 1 (just to be sure)

your query (url-wise, i don't know the php interface to solr) would need something like

```
<query>&bq=rooms:avail^20.0&bq=rooms:part-avail^10.0...
```

suggestions: if you're using dismax query handler, it's addictive. this means you'll have to add a bigger boost than that (2000 instead of 20 for example) since it adds the boosting value to the query score

also, you should check [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_increase_the_score_for_specific_documents) from the solr wiki, which is better than any explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that I have to add a document to any possible travel date in my index?

As stated above I have a document per room and this document contains multiple from/till dates for each bookable period.

Comment: I don't think, you first run your normal query (all rooms in a certain timespan) and then you use your boosted values on sorting parameters. Just checked throu my code, and i'm doing the same way: if a value appears in a determinate field, that field has a big boost over it. Using php (or python, in my case) should help you refine way better the query (ex: use an if statement to decide if and what you want to boost etc)

Comment: Running the initial query and filter on the timespan would only show the available rooms. Removing this filter could result in a very huge amount of documents returned. Is there any possibility to create an "available" field on the fly when running the query and use this to boost the score? Like "completly available"^100 "partially available"^50 "not available" ^1? Or is it possible to let SolR return documents NOT matching a query? I feel like sortMissingLast could be helpful in some way here...

Comment: sortMissingLast will work only on sorting fields treated as strings. so if a document is missing that field, that document will come after in the queue. another option you have is cachinc (wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching) and doing some prewarming (since it caches SORTED documents based on a query... we do extensive use of that)... field creating on the fly, afaik, isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did some research and testing on the whole thing here... The currect and possibly best solution for my problem is to perform multiple queries against SolR. As suggested by Samuele I query SolR for all accomodations matching the given criteria and timespan in two steps.

1: Get all rooms matching and being available (this includes partially available rooms)
2: Get all unavailable rooms

The second query is obviously only performed when we need to show more results 'cos of the pagination.

After that all results from step 1 are postprocessed to figure out if they are available in the whole requested timespan.

A further "improvement" would be to introduce a new field in the schema: availableDay. For each bookable day there would be an entry for that date. This would split up the first query into two seperate ones. This is then only a matter of additional filters for SolR.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!